# FileNotFoundException even when file is in src folder

Tags: java, eclipse, fileinputstream

My problem is a bit different from the ones that are there in SO...I will try to explain..

My code pick up an `.xls` file from a location (`c:\codereview\`) and inserts data into that file. I was using full file path for this but realized my program is not portable.

So I copied my `xls` from `c:/` drive into the `src/` folder and I now I keep getting a `FileNotFoundException`.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("/src/New_Record.xls"));

HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

when i try to use:

```
FileInputStream file = (FileInputStream) Util.class.getResourceAsStream("New_Record.xls");


i get below exception:
```

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.closeInputStream(POIFSFileSystem.java:183)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.(POIFSFileSystem.java:145)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:322)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbook.java:303)

Basically I want to use a combination of FileInputStream and InputStream so that i can use that with HSSFWorkbook. InputStream is not compatible directly with it and FileInputStream is not compatible with this.getClass.getResourceStream.

Comment: Try to remove the leading `/`.

Comment: Have a look at the absolute file path in debugging mode, you can spot the error there.

Comment: Add a `resources/` folder in your `src/` folder. Then use the `ClassLoader.getResource()` method to load the resource. Also make sure that the file exists in your classpath.

Comment: Please post the exact error you're getting, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Your classpath will start from the directory above source so I would try src/New_Record.xls

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl...your suggestion worked for me...i used getClassLoader.getResource("New-Record.xls") and it returned me the path of the file.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl... i used 'URL stream = ClassName.class.getClassLoader.getResource("New-Record.xls")' and it returned me the path of the file. I then converted the variable stream to string and used it with FileInputStream as mentioned in original question and my issue got resolved...thanks a ton for the suggestion..i had one more doubt: When i print the path of the file it gives a temp location and not the /src/New_Record.xls location as i was expecting...C:/*/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/PLT/WEB-INF/classes/New_Record.xls is what is returned...any guesses why?